# How do I know what Phoenix and Absinthe are doing in terms of process spawning and message sending?

Tags: elixir, actor, absinthe

I have an Elixir Umbrella app, with Phoenix, Absinthe (graphQL). In `AppWeb`, my `AppWeb.Router` routes requests, handling `/graphql` with `Absinthe.Plug` and using `MyApp.Schema`.

In `AppWeb.Schema`, I import objects from numerous different schemas in different OTP applications using `import_types`. I will use `Users` as an example.

The `Users.Schema` has objects and fields, where eventually will `resolve &Resolvers.resolve_x/2`

I know that Phoenix is starting a new process on each request, the hexdocs `Absinthe.Schema` states *In Absinthe 1.5 schemas are built using the same process by which queries are executed.* Does that mean that each new process created by a request by phoenix, communicates with a single *schema* (`AppWeb.Schema`) process? If so, won't that create a bottleneck? If not, isn't that a lot of code (all resolvers and relevant functions from all OTP apps) to be transferred to the new schema process spawned every-time?

Answer (score 0):

> In Absinthe 1.5 schemas are built using the same process by which
> queries are executed.

This doesn't refer to a BEAM process but rather that in Absinthe 1.5 schema's are built using a similar method as to how queries are resolved.

There are two ways to build schema's in Absinthe.

1. Using the macro-based DSL, this is what was already available in Absinthe 1.4
2. Using the Graphql Schema Definition Language (SDL), in this case Absinthe parses the SDL and builds a schema from it, resolvers etc. can be attached using the hydration constructs.

After either of these ways to build a schema, its blueprint (AST of the schema) goes through a pipeline of phases in which e.g. validation takes place. This is what is referred to by 'same process`, as a graphql document in Absinthe also follows the route of *graphl document -> parse to AST blueprint -> validation -> other phases*.

Be default the compilation of the schema still happens at compile time, so no extra processes are spawned for a request.